# Insert stamp PDF with different position uipath and python?

Tags: python, c#, excel, pdf, uipath

I have some PDF files, I want to stamp on those PDF files but the location is not the same, is there any way to find the location in the file and stamp on that PDF? I use Uipath and Python

I still haven't found a solution yet

Comment: i closed it but it is fixed position, i want to find the location by keyword on the pdf to stamp

Comment: ah, So do you have a way to stamp the PDF with keywords on that PDF?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**disclaimer:** I am the author of `borb` the library used in this answer.

From what I understand of your question, you want to find a certain word on the page, and add a stamp on top of that.

Let's split that in two parts:

### Finding the position of a word on the page

```py
#!chapter_005/src/snippet_006.py
import typing
from borb.pdf import Document
from borb.pdf import PDF
from borb.toolkit import RegularExpressionTextExtraction


def main():

    # read the Document
    # fmt: off
    doc: typing.Optional[Document] = None
    l: RegularExpressionTextExtraction = RegularExpressionTextExtraction("[lL]orem .* [dD]olor")
    with open("output.pdf", "rb") as in_file_handle:
        doc = PDF.loads(in_file_handle, [l])
    # fmt: on

    # check whether we have read a Document
    assert doc is not None

    # print matching groups
    for i, m in enumerate(l.get_matches()[0]):
        print("%d %s" % (i, m.group(0)))
        for r in m.get_bounding_boxes():
            print(
                "\t%f %f %f %f" % (r.get_x(), r.get_y(), r.get_width(), r.get_height())
            )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

In this snippet we use `RegularExpressionTextExtraction` to process the `Page` events (rendering text, images, etc). This class acts as an `EventListener`, and keeps track of which text (being rendered) matches the given regex.

We can then print that text, and its position.

### Putting a stamp on a page, at a given position

In the next snippet, we are going to:

- create a PDF containing some text
- add a rubber stamp (annotation) on that page, at precise coordinates

You can of course modify this snippet to only add the stamp, and to work from an existing PDF (rather than create one).

```py
#!chapter_006/src/snippet_005.py
from decimal import Decimal

from borb.pdf.canvas.layout.annotation.rubber_stamp_annotation import (
    RubberStampAnnotation,
    RubberStampAnnotationIconType,
)
from borb.pdf.canvas.geometry.rectangle import Rectangle
from borb.pdf import SingleColumnLayout
from borb.pdf import PageLayout
from borb.pdf import Paragraph
from borb.pdf import Document
from borb.pdf import Page
from borb.pdf.page.page_size import PageSize
from borb.pdf import PDF


def main():

    doc: Document = Document()

    page: Page = Page()
    doc.add_page(page)

    layout: PageLayout = SingleColumnLayout(page)

    layout.add(
        Paragraph(
            """
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
                        Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
                        Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
                        Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                        """
        )
    )

    # This is where the stamp is added
    page_width: Decimal = PageSize.A4_PORTRAIT.value[0]
    page_height: Decimal = PageSize.A4_PORTRAIT.value[1]
    s: Decimal = Decimal(100)
    page.add_annotation(
        RubberStampAnnotation(
            Rectangle(
                page_width / Decimal(2) - s / Decimal(2),
                page_height / Decimal(2) - s / Decimal(2),
                s,
                s,
            ),
            name=RubberStampAnnotationIconType.CONFIDENTIAL,
        )
    )

    # store
    with open("output.pdf", "wb") as out_file_handle:
        PDF.dumps(out_file_handle, doc)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The result should be something like this:

[image]

In order to change the appearance of the stamp, I encourage you to check out the documentation.